# Multiple Where using Querys in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause

I have this code :

```
if ($tipo==='d') {
    $movimentos=movimento::where('tipo',$d)->WhereIn('destino',$idcontas)->whereBetween('data', [$compdata, Carbon::now()])->get(); 

} elseif ($tipo==='c') {
    $movimentos=movimento::where('tipo',$d)->WhereIn('origem',$idcontas)->whereBetween('data', [$compdata, Carbon::now()])->get();  

} else {
    $movimentos=movimento::where('tipo',$d)->WhereIn('origem',$idcontas)->WhereIn('destino',$idcontas)->whereBetween('data', [$compdata, Carbon::now()])->get();    
}
```

I've seen a lot of posts regarding multiple Where in laravel but not a single one talking about those special wheres.
The code i have atm doesnt work but if i have only one where like the whereBetween one it does.

Can someone help me making them all working fine?

Comment: What error do you get when you run the above code?

Comment: none , just doesnt show nothing when i output $movimentos , but for example if i only have one where or wherein or whatever it works ...

Comment: Ok.I am just going to ask you some questions, since there seems to be nothing wrong with the syntax or logic per se. Are you sure that correct data exists with all the filters set? Do you get back the expected data when you run the mysql version of the queries in phpMyAdmin or shell?

Comment: Instead of `get()`, use `toSql()`.  That will give you a good idea of where your sql might be wrong.

Comment: ty , now i understand whats wrong